# Dispatch action when component is created

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component like this:

```
class FormItem extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props){
        super();
        props.dispatch(setFormCreated(props.formBuilder, props.formId)); 
    }

   render(){
       ...
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        doValidation: state.formsReducer.validationRequested
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onValidationSucceed: formId =>  dispatch(setFormValidationSucceed(formId)),
    onValidationFailed: formId => dispatch(setFormValidationFailed(formId))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FormItem);
```

I want to dispatch an action when the component is created. Line 5:

```
props.dispatch(setFormCreated(props.formBuilder, props.formId));
```

But I got:

> TypeError: props.dispatch is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have props passed in super before you use the props inside the constructor:

```
super(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onValidationSucceed: formId =>  dispatch(setFormValidationSucceed(formId)),
    onValidationFailed: formId => dispatch(setFormValidationFailed(formId))
    onFormCreated: (formBuilder, formId) => dispatch(setFormCreated(formBuilder, formId))
});
```

In your component you could then use the following (I would place your code in `componentDidMount`). This also assumes you're passing `formBuilder` and `formId` as props.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { onFormCreated, formBuilder, formId } = this.props;
  onFormCreated(formBuilder, formId)
}
```